# how to make loop to create a graph of every column in dataset in python

Tags: python, loops

how can I make a loop to plot figure of each column??  i want to draw the graph of each column in python so i can see the outlier of each column

```
for i in d:
      if d[i].dtypes!="object":
         print (sns.distplot(d[i]))
```

Comment: Also use `df.select_dtypes(np.number)` to keep the numerical type columns

Comment: What is `type(d)`?

Comment: You are providing very little information about your context. What is `d`, for example? What have you already tried? Please expand.

Comment: d is data frame which has all columns of data

Comment: @narendra-choudhary   d is a data frame